# Кодировка в AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, кодировка

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Кракозябры замучали! Хотя я и все сделал.

В документе указал

```
meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"
```

В файле PHP

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
```

И все равно не помогает!

Comment: А сам файл в какой кодировке?

Comment: Какой файл?Там где ява?Ну вроде в windows-1251 !Вот пишу с помощью notepad++ ,там написано ANSI!!Я потерялся,короче == windows-1251.

Comment: Используйте utf-8 и забудьте об этих проблемах.

Comment: АА,,это не выход!!!у мя весь сайт на windows-1251 !!

Comment: Попробуйте послать запрос с помощью этой библы: jsHttpRequest (dklab.ru, они же писали денвер). Библа поддерживает кодировку.

Comment: И еще. В БД сохраняются кракозябры. То есть это проблема не вывода, а сохранения в БД.

Comment: Используйте в БД utf-8.

Comment: Вот в чем проблема: в БД Сравнение == utf-8, но при извлечении я поставил mysql_query('set names cp1251'). Да и проблема в передаче через AJAX. Ведь без AJAX все пахало.

Comment: аякс работает только с utf8

Comment: Вот,,а я пробую перекодировать ,а разницы нет(
$name = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', $name);

Comment: Используйте вместо iconv() - mb_convert_encoding()

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас все тексты в windows-1251.

В начале страницы

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
```

Перед отправкой запроса на сервер

```
XmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "windows-1251");
XmlHttp.send(encodeURI(req));
```

В начале страницы обрабатывающей запрос

```
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
```

Полученный запрос перекодируйте

```
while(list($key,$val) = each($_POST))
{
    $_POST[$key]=iconv("UTF-8","windows-1251",$val);
}
```

echo будет выводить уже в готовом виде windows 1251.

Если Вы используете MySQL, то сразу после соединения с базой, укажите кодировку данных в базе и какую вы хотите получить на выходе. Здесь предполагается, что везде windows 1251

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_client = cp1251");
mysql_query("SET collation_connection=cp1251_general_ci");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = cp1251");
```

Answer (score 2):

Перепишите все под UTF-8 станет намного проще. Да и не забудьте в php убрать BOM.

Comment: а как в php убрать BOM.!!Что єто такое?

Comment: BOM (англ. Byte Order Mark, BOM) - Это метка порядка байтов Юникода, также её часто называют сигнатурой (соответственно, UTF-8 и UTF-8 with Signature). В большинстве редакторах они автоматически добавляются и это часто рушит скрипты с cookie (других примеров пока не знаю). Такие редакторы, как Notepad++, Notepad2 и Kate позволяют явно указывать, следует ли добавлять сигнатуру при сохранении UTF-файлов.

Comment: все спасибо,перевел все в utf8 ,,теперь надо пробовать ,

Comment: и все равно,,ajax передает крякозябры!

Comment: Все файлы в utf8?
java? php?
Хэдеры тоже исправлены?

Comment: да!!все!!и пхп ,и с бд вытаскиваю с mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

все в кодировке utf-8 без BOM

Comment: http://elbooks.org.ua/index.php - AJAX в регистрации.

Comment: У вас reg_p.php в кодировке ISO-8859-5, попробуйте туда добавить хэдер с utf-8.

Comment: Попробуйте у себя поднять сервер и воспользоваться теми же файлами. Как вариант Денвер или Вертриго, но лучше самому собрать.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду поставить у ся на комп серв?Это вариант для проверки но не больше(прийдется искать другой хост,спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Если заработает, то придется искать, если нет, может еще вариант какой найдется.

Comment: @Сергей @Ivan Уважаемые участники форума, пожалуйста, не используйте комментарии в режиме чата: это приводит к постоянному поднятию темы наверх. Если вам интересно разобраться в проблеме, вы всегда можете обменяться контактами и общаться напрямую.

Comment: @Хэшкод, я собственно поэтому и поднимал тему с личными сообщениями.
Не все пишут контактные данные и получается, что пообщаться на определенную тему, кроме как через комментарии невозможно. Возможно поднятие jabber сервера было бы панацеей. Кроме того в профиле просто отсутствует место для указание того же джаббера.

Comment: @Сергей Рано или поздно что-то вроде комнат появится. :) В профиле есть графа "О себе" - туда можно вписать любые контактные данные.

Comment: Графа о себе логически не подходит для таких целей, даже если это возможно.